# No route found from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have added a second bundle and when I try to open some url from that bundle, I keep getting an error that the route was not found. Adding the same route to the main bundle works perfectly.

What's wrong?

[image]

This is my project structure. I also:
- added the UserBundle to AppKernel.php (IDE shows the class exists)
- use AppBundle\Controller namespace in AppBundle, and UserBundle\Controller namespace in UserBundle

The controller I try to access from the UserBundle looks like this:

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="user_login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
       return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked up your `config/routing.yml` file? Even thought, you're using `Annotations`, you still need to tell Symfony to inspect your newly created bundle.

Comment: Yup, missed it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to add the `UserBundle` to your `routing.yml` configuration. You should have something like this in the `routing.yml`:

```
user_bundle:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```